# BI Publisher not showing date information

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have a sql query which formats the date and shows correct output in SQL developer. But when used as a BI report it is coming as blank. What could be the reason?

```
select to_date(END_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the date column is now changed to `to_date(END_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')` the report is still pointing to `END_DATE` and not `to_date(END_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY')` hence use the alias name and update your query as follows:

```
select to_char(END_DATE,'DD-MON-yyyy') as END_DATE from dual;
```

This will keep the data model and the report definition in sync.

Also if you are changing the data types ensure you are mappings are updated by going to the report.